# Crear un MySQL Procedure para recorrer una tabla y luego insertar el id en otra

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando un **PROCEDURE** en MySQL para recorrer una tabla e insertar el ID en otra.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
DEClARE parents_id CURSOR FOR select id from parent
     WHILE parents_id EOF DO
        INSERT INTO parentSubscription(code, active, parent_id) VALUES ('aaa', true, parents_id);
    END WHILE;
END;
```

No estoy seguro de como realizar, como tomo la variable ID del select y luego como recorro el while realizando el insert con el id de la tabla parent.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien un CURSOR es una opción válida, ¿realmente necesita un CURSOR?. Aquí la documentación [13.6.6 Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) (en Inglés).

Si el caso de uso realmente requiere un CURSOR, puede hacer algo como:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myproc`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `NOT_FOUND` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE `_parents_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DEClARE `cursor_parents_id` CURSOR FOR SELECT `id` FROM `parent`;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `NOT_FOUND` := TRUE;

  OPEN `cursor_parents_id`;
  FETCH `cursor_parents_id` INTO `_parents_id`;

  WHILE NOT `NOT_FOUND` DO
    INSERT INTO `parentSubscription` (`code`, `active`, `parent_id`)
    VALUES ('aaa', TRUE, `_parents_id`);

    FETCH `cursor_parents_id` INTO `_parents_id`;
  END WHILE;

  CLOSE `cursor_parents_id`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Sin embargo, otra opción puede ser la siguiente:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myproc`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `parentSubscription` (`code`, `active`, `parent_id`)
  SELECT 'aaa', TRUE, `id`
  FROM `parent`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Ver ejemplo en [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f676c789cd34371768d0e59b62c8e5f3).